# Are these suspensions or appoggiaturas in Haydn's Surprise Symphony?

Tags: harmony

The IB Revision Guide states that there are suspensions in the bars below (top line, violin 1). The bass harmony moves from C to F. The first 2 notes of the third bar in the violin B - A form tension resolution as found in a suspension, but even though the previous note at the end of the second bar is also a B, this note is not part of the harmony of C or F, so in my mind is not the "preparation" required for a suspension. According to the author there are 3 suspensions here, but I think the other 2 are the same. Am I wrong or would it be better to call these something else such as appoggiaturas?

[image]

Comment: Clefs? Sure, we can probably tell from context, but why but the burden on the reader?

Comment: You're right, sorry Michael, will include next time.

Answer (score 1):

The distinction between suspension and appoggiature isn't set in stone, despite the opinion of some textbooks.  And 'unprepared suspensions' are definitely a thing. I prefer to say an appoggiatura is just a suspension notated in small type as a gracenote.

However, if you're f0llowing an exam syllabus which insists an unprepared suspension must be called an appoggiatura, you'd better go with the flow.

I see two suspensions here (the second B and the second G), and three passing notes (the first B, first G and the final E).  Can a suspension be prepared by a passing note?  For this particular examination the answer seems to be 'yes'.

Comment: Thanks Laurence, the exam syllabus doesn't insist on one or the other. However, as the example in the image is stated as having suspensions in the IB Revision Guide, I think to explain it to the students using your way of thinking might be the least confusing for them. If there was no additional B and G before these, I would definitely not think of them as suspensions, but in this case I don't see any problem in explaining them as suspensions that are prepared by a passing note rather than a chord tone.

Answer (score 1):

> ...so in my mind is not the "preparation" required for a suspension.

I agree with you, because otherwise you end up with just a *generic* notion of non-chord tone with no regard to approach or resolution. Since there are historic words for various non-chord tone type it stands to reason we should pay attention to the details that *distinguish* them.

[image]

The definitions of *appoggiatura* I have seen specify an approach *by leap* so by that standard there aren't appoggiaturas here.

However, there is something called a *sighing figure* an accented, one step descent with a slur over it, a non-chord tone to a chord tone. I think sighing figures are thought of as a kind of appoggiatura. I see the term *appoggiatura signing figure* is often used.

[image]

So, while those tones may not fit a textbook appoggiatura definition, as a sighing figure that sort of have an appoggiatura feel.

Comment: Thanks Michael, I haven't heard of sighing figures before, must look more into these. Are you sure the definitions of appoggiatura that specify an "approach by leap" are correct? On Wikipedia it says: " The added non-chord note, or auxiliary note, is typically one degree higher or lower than the principal note".

Comment: Yes, I've seen that definition in several sources. To some degree the specifics of the definitions are the result of making a full list of unique NCT types. Appoggiatura approached by leap is more or less a logical necessity if you want to have _meaningful_ definitions for things like passing tone, neighbor tone, suspension, etc.

Comment: Excluding cases of two unresolved NCTs, and assuming downward resolution, you _need_ the appoggiatura to be approached by leap. A step from below is a neighbor tone, step from above a passing tone, repeated tone is a suspension. _Categorically_ the other approach option is _leap_, so appoggiatura is approached by leap.

Comment: Probably that kind of classification is a modern textbook thing, attempting to classify all NCTs systematically. Older terminology seems looser. That's why I made the point about "sighing figure." I take the meaning to be a kind of _appoggiatura feel_ despite not fitting the modern category.

Comment: Things can get dicey... consider a melodic neighbor figure, like `E F E` what if the two `E`'s are chord tones... but of different chords? In the Kostka _Harmony_ textbook, that fits none of the categories perfectly! It's a bit neighbor, a bit escape tone, a bit appoggiatura, depending on where the accent is. But the text also provides this footnote: _NCT terminology is not standardized, and your instructor may prefer that you use different labels and definitions. However, the definitions given here are widely used._

Comment: Ah, so am I right in my understanding of what you're saying that the term appoggiatura would basically be redundant if only applied to an approach by step because we already have passing tone, neighbor tone, suspension, etc. for this?

Comment: Yes, I think so.